# Get latest row and sum of a column in it togather

Tags: sql-server

In my table I have three columns `amount`,`date`,`memberID`. Now I want to get Latest amount inserted in to the table and the sum of whole amount inserted so far.

My Query was like this

```
SELECT  amount , SUM(amount) as TotalAmount FROM [Transactions] 
WHERE memberid = 1629 Order By Date DESC
```

But this throws an error like this

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Transactions.amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT amount AS LatestAmount,
       (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM [Transactions]) AS TotalAmount
FROM [Transactions]
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM [Transactions])
```

Note that in the event of a tie for more than one latest amount, the above query would produce one record for each tying transaction.  If you want only one result, and you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, you can use `TOP(1)` to limit to a single result:

```
SELECT TOP(1) amount AS LatestAmount,
       (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM [Transactions]) AS TotalAmount
FROM [Transactions]
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM [Transactions])
```

Comment: I would recommend using `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY DATE DESC` instead of `date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM [Transactions])`

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `Group by` clause

```
SELECT  amount , SUM(amount) as TotalAmount FROM [Transactions] 
GROUP BY amount WHERE memberid = 1629 Order By Date DESC
```